# Использование вектора и рекурсия в быстрой сортировке

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сортировка, c++11, вектор

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему в этом коде быстрой сортировки:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void QuickSort(vector<int>& in, int left, int right)
{
    if(right - left == 1)
    {
        return;
    }
    int x = in[rand() % in.size()];
    int m = left;
    for(int i = 0; i < in.size(); i++)
    {
        if(in[i] < x)
        {
            swap(in[i], in[m]);
            m++;
        }
    }
    QuickSort(in, left, m);
    QuickSort(in, m + 1, right);
}
int main()
{
    vector<int> a = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 10, 8, 14, 7, 6, 11};
    int left = 0;
    int right = a.size() - 1;
    QuickSort(a, left, right);
    for(int x : a)
    {
        cout << x << ' ';
    }
}
```

в последний элемент вектора записывается какое-то рандомное отрицательное большое число, при том, что в первый элемент вектора записывается верное число  - 5? В чем ошибка?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119064/discussion-on-question-by-prostak-------).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Код подразумевает использование [схемы разделения Ломуто](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme) (а не Хоара), однако реализация содержит некоторые проблемы:

-на подмассиве длиной 1 условие выхода не выполняется (оно для длины 2)
-выбор опоры и цикл проводится по всему массиву, а не по нужной части
-даже если это поправить, значение `m` не является правильным разделительным индексом, т.к. часто `in[m] > x (pivot)`

Рабочий вариант ([ideone](https://ideone.com/HGBM3S)) со случайным выбором опорного элемента (pivot)

```
void QuickSort(vector<int>& in, int left, int right)
{
    if (right <= left)
        return;
    int ipi = left + rand() % (right - left + 1);
    swap(in[ipi], in[right]);
    int x = in[right];
    int m = left;
    for (int i = left; i < right; i++)
        if (in[i] <= x)
            swap(in[i], in[m++]);
    swap(in[m], in[right]);
    QuickSort(in, left, m);
    QuickSort(in, m + 1, right);
}
```